# External monitor over the air with Macbook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, display, screen-sharing

I have purchased a second-hand MacBook (13 inch, white) which is quite cool. Now i want to connect it to my external monitor and i have got a Mini-DVI-to-DVI cable from a friend of mine:

[image]

However, my monitor's DVI input is damaged and i must use a VGA-cable with a DVI-to-VGA adapter on one end:

[image]

Furthermore, i can not connect this DVI-adapter to the Mini-DVI-to-DVI cable because it has somehow 4 pins more around the "bar" (hope you can see what i mean)... this is the reason why i am searching for a method to connect my Samsung 940 BW as an external monitor - prefferable via network. Is there any Tool/Program that will work with my OS X 10.7 on my MacBook and Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC and extend the "viewport" from the Mac to the monitor? Air Display does **not** support *Mac to Windows* and MaxiVista is only for Windows!

Comment: @bmike: The links are already included in my post :P What ideas do you have?

Comment: I added them - wow, they're big. Even though it's a nice story why you want a software solution, you might want to edit this to simply ask the question first. Then say you want a software solution since cabling is difficult / not optimal for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was `ScreenRecycler` which is working as expected. It creates a virtual desktop which can be accessed via VNC on my Windows machine and i can work with that, althoug i have some problems connecting if i am not connected to the same WLAN but i will ask another question for that!

Answer (score 2):

Those extra four pins on your DVI to VGA adapter actually carry the VGA signal; the adapter doesn't actually do any adapting. (The terminology is: DVI-D is digital-only like your mini-DVI to DVI adapter, while DVI-I carries both DVI and VGA, like your cable.)

The hardware solution is to get a mini-DVI to VGA adapter (from [Apple](http://store.apple.com/us/product/M9320G/A) or [elsewhere](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Mini-DVI+to+VGA+adapter)).

Answer (score 0):

RE: ".. Is there any Tool/Program that will work with my OS X 10.7 on my MacBook and Windows 7 Ultimate on my PC and extend the "viewport" from the Mac to the monitor? Air Display does not support Mac to Windows and MaxiVista is only for Windows!"

Correct me if I am wrong, But from the way you are wording this, I believe what you are trying to do is use one keyboard and mouse (plugged into either a Mac or a Windows PC) across multiple computer displays (so that you can move your mouse off the edge of your monitor running on Windows 7, and then see your mouse cursor pop up at the other edge of your monitor plugged in to your Mac?

If so, this sourceforge project should do the trick : [Synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/running.html)

(Synergy has already had updates to work with Lion)

Comment: I do not want this. Here is an example: The screen resolution of my MBP is not that high and for Xcode I need more and connecting my monitor is not possible due to the mentioned problems. I want a software solution to move my "Mac"window (here e.g. Xcode) to my "Windows"monitor.

Comment: Ok, you can get a Mac desktop on a windows pc by using osx screen sharing on the Mac, and using ultra-vnc client on windows : http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1204794